# save not throwing error even if record with key exist in db

Tags: hibernate

I wrote this code:

```
            Account ac= new Account();
    ac.setId(1);
    ac.setType("checking");
    ac.setAmount(12344.43);
    //Transient

    Configuration cfg= new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    try(Session s=sf.openSession();Session s1=sf.openSession()){
    s.beginTransaction();
    s.save(ac);//dirty checking
    ac.setAmount(3000);
    s.flush();
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    ac.setAmount(5000);
    Account ac1=s1.get(Account.class, 1);
    ac1.setAmount(8000);
    s1.save(ac1);
    s1.beginTransaction().commit();
    }
    sf.close();
```

In second session when we saving the account object again it should throw an error but it does not. Any pointers regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once we have done  ac1.setAmount(8000);
the database would be updated with the latest data. But since the account object is already associated to the session with latest data, no save query would be fired to the db hence no error.

To illustrate,

```
        Account ac= new Account();
    ac.setId(2);
    ac.setType(AccountType.CHECKING);
    ac.setDateOfOpening(LocalDateTime.now());
    ac.setAmount(12344.43);

    Configuration cfg= new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    Session s=sf.openSession();
    s.save(ac);
    ac.setType(AccountType.CHECKING);
    s.beginTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
    sf.close();
```

It does not fire any update query in db, only 1 insert. So if the state is not changing, and it is in persistent state ,it does not perform update/ save

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saving on the same id,

```
Account ac1=s1.get(Account.class, 1);
```

You'll only be updating the existing record (with ID = 1).

If you are interested in learning the behaviour of save and other persisting methods in-depth, a good article is avaialble at http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate .

Comment: I read the complete article which states that if we save the detached object, a new row is inserted in the db, not updated. Even for the code pasted above, if we run it by "show_sql" set to true, it is an update query. I think the article talks nowhere about save updating the existing row.